# How to call Same vf page from another VF page with Output Fields?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I have two VFpages

In 1st VF Page:

1. I have a 3 input field and I am entering data
2. I have a button(Standard/custom).
3. When I click on this button, It should redirect to another page(2nd VF Page) with the same fields with output fields along with the data I have entered

   ```
   <apex:page standardController="Contact" >
   <apex:form >

   <script>
    function OpenVfpageConfrim(){
   var confirmFlag =confirm('Do you want to open a new visualforce page?');
   if(confirmFlag == true)
      window.open('/apex/anothervfpage');
      }</script>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact">

       <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
           <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Birthdate}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Open vf Page" onclick="OpenVfpageConfrim()"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   ```

   [image]

In 2nd VF page

1. It should display the same 1st VF Page with output fields
2. There should be a button to SAVE This data into the database

   ```
    <apex:page Controller="ContactControllerr" >
    <apex:form >

       <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!samepage}" var="c">
     <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
     <apex:outputField value="{!c.Firstname}"/>
     </apex:column>

     <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
     <apex:outputField value="{!c.Lastname}"/>
     </apex:column>

     <apex:column headerValue="Birthdate">
     <apex:outputField value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>
     </apex:column>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   ```

   ```
   public with sharing class ContactControllerr {
   public Contact c { get; set; }
   public List<Contact> samepage { get; set; }
   public ContactControllerr(){
          c=new Contact();
      }
        public PageReference save() {
         insert c;  
     samepage= [select id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Birthdate from Contact 
      where id=:c.id];

   return null;
       }
      }
   ```

   [image]

   Data is not coming and saving into the database?

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you really need two pages for this? Some conditional rendering and some simple re-rendering may be enough to accomplish this. Also, how much do you know about the "viewstate" of a visualforce page? Splitting this across two separate pages is possible, but I think the single-page + rerender approach would be faster/easier.

Comment: Rerender approach means I am not sure about Derek. Can you please share any example or suggest me how to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example on how to implement this kind of functionality.

> VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TestCreateContactCont">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact" rendered="{!editPage}">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!ct.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ct.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ct.Birthdate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}" reRender="theForm"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact" rendered="{!!editPage}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ct}" var="c">
                <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Firstname}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Lastname}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Birthdate">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

             <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

> Apex Class Extention

```
public class TestCreateContactCont {
    public Contact ct{get;set;}
    public Boolean editPage {get;set;}

    public TestCreateContactCont(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        ct = (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
        editPage = true;
    }

    public void next() {
        editPage = false;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        insert ct;
        return new PageReference('/'+ct.Id);
    }
}
```

As @Derek F mentioned you can achieve this without having to use two controllers and two pages. In a complex scenario where if you must use two controllers and two pages, I'd suggest you share the same controller between vf pages; which enables you to easily pass values.